# For loop error type mismatch in Scala

Tags: scala, for-loop, type-mismatch

i'm learning Scala, but I'm not able go trough the for loop in this code

```
    def adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray: Array[Int]): Int = {

    var maxSoFar = 0
    var maxHere = 0

    //for (i <- 0:Int to (inputArray.length-1))      <- error
    for (i <- 0 to inputArray.length-1)            //<- error
    {
          if( maxHere * inputArray(i) > 0 )
                maxHere *= inputArray(i)
          else
                maxHere = 0

          if( maxHere > maxSoFar )
                maxSoFar = maxHere

          maxSoFar
    }

}
```

Compiler results:

(without :Int)

```
  file.scala on line 6: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Int
        for (i <- 0 to inputArray.length-1)
               ^
```

(with :Int)

```
file.scala on line 6: error: identifier expected but integer literal found.
    for (i <- 0:Int to (inputArray.length - 1) )
                                            ^
file.scala on line 19: error: ')' expected but '}' found.
}
^
```

What is wrong? How can i solve it?

Thanks a lot, Davide

Comment: If `maxHere` starts at `0`, how can `maxHere * inputArray(i)` ever be `> 0`?

Comment: yeah my fault, i've corrected it with 1 as soon as the for loop worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`adjacentElementsProduct` needs to return a `Int`, you need to put what you want to return at the end of the method (outside the for-loop).

Also you can simplify `for (i <- 0 to inputArray.length-1)` to `for (i <- inputArray)` and replace `inputArray(i)` with `i`.

Answer (score 2):

If what you're trying to do is return the maximum product of adjacent non-zero integers, here's a more Scala-esque approach.

```
def adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray: Array[Int]): Int =
  inputArray.scanLeft(0)((a,b) => if (a==0) b else a*b).max
```

---

**explanation** (somewhat simplified)

Think of it this way: `myArray.scanLeft(init)(op)` will build a new `Array` that looks something like:

```
Array( init
     , op(init,             myArray(0))
     , op(previousOpResult, myArray(1))
     , op(previousOpResult, myArray(2))
     . . .
     )
```

Comment: oh ok, let me understand with that structure it scan the array from 0 to the end i guess, and it create an external temporary structure with all the products so it can find the max value?

Comment: @DavideAmbrosi; Explanation added.

Answer (score 1):

the return value `maxSoFar` should out of the for loop {},like this :

```
def adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray: Array[Int]): Int = {

    var maxSoFar = 0
    var maxHere = 0

    //for (i <- 0:Int to (inputArray.length-1))      <- error
    for (i <- 0 to inputArray.length-1)            //<- error
    {
          if( maxHere * inputArray(i) > 0 )
                maxHere *= inputArray(i)
          else
                maxHere = 0

          if( maxHere > maxSoFar )
                maxSoFar = maxHere


    }
    maxSoFar

}
```